# Java or Python for Google App Engine not knowing either language?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I have a few project ideas that I'd like to deploy on GAE. I'm interested in developing a logging application for amateur radio contacts, shortwave, and utility monitoring. More complex projects include satellite tracking, audio streaming from multiple radios, and radio remote control including transmitting and receiving.

I'm taking Java and Python languages through my local junior college, so I don't know which language is suitable for these projects. What are the strengths and weaknesses of each language for developing on GAE specifically, especially audio and number crunching for the tracking app? I'm not asking for a general comparison between the two languages, only as they are used on GAE. The end result is to tie them into my website which is hosted on Google, with some of the apps publicly available, some privately available to friends.

If it helps, I have the most experience with Perl, bash, followed by C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is simpler. Since you specifically mentioned number crunching, select Python 2.7 (experimental version) of GAE which includes numpy (you can crunch a lot of numbers with it) built-in. Java has a lot of libraries but numpy is the defacto number-crunching package for Python. So if you develop it on Python, the code could be understood by almost any Python developer with numpy experience. And since you are new to both Java and Python, you would find Python much easier to learn. Regarding performance, Numpy is right up there with the fastest of implementations (Only a few libraries in C/C++ beat Numpy in terms of pure speed but speed also depends on GAE's implementation)